# Class detection and alert

Tags: html, css

I have a nested list that contains list items having a class which specifies the list level.

I wish to detect which level is clicked but my code is not working..can someone put me right pls.

```js
$("li").click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('sub-level3')){
        alert("this list item contains class-sub-level3");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('sub-level4')) {
        alert("this list item contains class-sub-level3");
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="has-dropdown sub-level3 not-click moved">
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
</li>
<li class="has-dropdown sub-level4 not-click moved">
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Uhm ... those messages are identical.

Comment: Have to tried to log something in the console in the else ? or to log `e` to see what you are using ? `window.console.log()` is always a good debug friend :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as expected. You either forgot to include jQuery or the duplicate message confused you. As you can see it works:

```js
$("li").click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('sub-level3')){
        alert("Level 3");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('sub-level4')) {
        alert("Level 4");
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="has-dropdown sub-level3 not-click moved">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-dropdown sub-level3 not-click moved">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
    </li>
    <ul>
        <li class="has-dropdown sub-level4 not-click moved">
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Manfred, you are correct but would you know why Im getting the multiple popup messages?

Comment: @BobtheBuilder I'm not getting multiple with the code you provided or the one I posted - the issue must be somewhere else in your code. (maybe you set the click handler for multiple classes?)

Comment: It looks like I have a strange propagation issue

Comment: but I cant use event.preventdefault() nor event.stoppropogation as this inteferes with what happens after the click.

Answer (score 0):

I had a propogation type issue when I clicked sub-level3 it fired sub-level4 as well but I could not use the methods I mentioned, fixed now with the following code, thanks all!

```
 $("li.sub-level3").click(function (e) {

                alert("sub3");
            });

            $(document).on('click', 'li.sub-level4', function (e) {

                alert("sub4");

            });
```